# SharePoint 2013 SQL cluster problem with secondary node

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, replication, availability

I have a SQL server cluster with two nodes. We've configured availability groups for databases, but
there seems to be a weird issue. SharePoint Secure store database exists only on the secondary node and because of that, I cannot add this database to the availability group. This causes issues with PSconfig etc.
because the Primary node does not have this database.

What's the best practice to resolve this? Do I copy the database from secondary node to primary or what would be the best way to fix this issue?